# Как переписать решение без использования циклов?

Tags: python, алгоритм, олимпиада

> Задача из олимпиады 8 класс
>
> Имеется N кг металлического сплава. Из него изготавливают заготовки массой K кг каждая. После этого из каждой заготовки вытачиваются детали массой M кг каждая (из каждой заготовки вытачивают максимально возможное количество деталей).
>
> Если от заготовок после этого что-то остается, то этот материал возвращают к началу производственного цикла и сплавляют с тем, что осталось при изготовлении заготовок. Если того сплава, который получился, достаточно для изготовления хотя бы одной заготовки, то из него снова изготавливают заготовки, из них — детали и т.д.
>
> Напишите программу, которая вычислит, какое количество деталей может быть получено по этой технологии из имеющихся исходно N кг сплава.
>
> Программа получает на вход три натуральных числа N, K, M.
>
> Выведите одно число — количество деталей, которое может получиться по такой технологии.
>
> **Запрещено использовать циклы(**

Смог написать только с использованием цикла:

```
N = int(input())
K = int(input())
M = int(input())

count_d = 0

while N >= K:
    count_z = N // K
    count_d += count_z * (K // M)
    N -= count_z * (K // M) * M

print(count_d)
```

> ```
> Входные данные: 10 5 2
>
> Выходные: 4
> ```

> ```
> Входные данные: 13 5 3
>
> Выходные: 3
> ```

> ```
> Входные данные: 14 5 3
>
> Выходные: 4
> ```

> ```
> Входные данные: 13 9 4
>
> Выходные: 2
> ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```py
N = int(input())
K = int(input())
M = int(input())

q = K // M
M *= q

print(((N - K + 1) // M + bool((N - K + 1) % M)) * q)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111300/discussion-on-answer-by-rew----8-).

Answer (score 4):

Ну переделайте цикл на рекурсию (что кстати на практике делать не надо, а даже наоборот рекурсию надо переделать в цикл):

```
N = int(input())
K = int(input())
M = int(input())

count_d = 0

def f(n):
    global N, K, M, count_d
    if not (n >= K):
        return
    count_z = N // K
    count_d += count_z * (K // M)
    N -= count_z * (K // M) * M
    f(N)
f(N)
print(count_d)
```

**P.S.** У вас кстати очень неплохой питон. Особенно для восьмиклассника. Кст код, который я написал хуже т.к. он больше юзает стековое пространство и еще использует глобалы. Нo зато — без циклов.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
k = int(input())
m = int(input())
i = k - k % m
n = abs(n - k + i) - i
count = (n // i + 1) * (k // m)
print(count)
```

Вот решение с использованием модуля

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Ответ може и не в тему, но стоит добавить парочку ограничений, чтобы решение проходила несколько стрессс-тестов.

```
inp_numbers = input()
inp_numbers = inp_numbers.split(' ')
inp_numbers = [int(i) for i in inp_numbers]

n = inp_numbers[0]
k = inp_numbers[1]
m = inp_numbers[2]

if n == 0 or k == 0 or m == 0:
    print(0)
elif m > k or k > n or m > n:
    print(0)
else:
    cnt_pt = 0

    while n >= k:
        cnt_wp = n // k
        cnt_pt += cnt_wp * (k // m)
        n -= cnt_wp * (k // m) * m

    print(cnt_pt)
```